# How to center widgets vertically and horizontally in window with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to center 3 labels vertically within the window. The labels are centered on-top of each other, but they are fixed at the top of the window.

What do I need to do to have them sit right in the middle of the window, (vertically and horizontally)?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Question 2")
root.configure(background="green")
Label(root, text = "RED", fg="red", bg="black").pack()
Label(root, text = "WHITE", fg="white", bg="black").pack()
Label(root, text = "BLUE", fg="blue", bg="black").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this case you can simply use a `Frame` widget as the parent of the labels and then pack the frame by setting the `expand` option to `True`:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Question 2")
root.configure(background="green")

parent = Frame(root)
Label(parent, text = "RED", fg="red", bg="black").pack(fill="x")
Label(parent, text = "WHITE", fg="white", bg="black").pack(fill="x")
Label(parent, text = "BLUE", fg="blue", bg="black").pack(fill="x")
parent.pack(expand=1)  # same as expand=True

root.mainloop()
```